# Why is the form still submitted?

Tags: javascript, validation

I wonder why is the form still submitted instead of show the validation results. I have tried also having an onclick event at input type line but also no joy :-(

This is the form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
  "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>Submit a runner time</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="TMA02validationSubmitResultForm.js"></script> 
<hr/>
<h1>Submit a runner time</h1>
<hr/>
Note: all fields marked '*' are mandatory.
<p/>
<form action="http://jdm423.tt284.open.ac.uk/uploadblock2/storedata.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" id="submitrunnertime" name="submitrunnertime">
<table>
<div id="error"> </div>
<tr><td>Runner ID*</td>
<td><input type="text" onblur="validateRunnerId()" id="RunnerId" name="RunnerId"  size="5" maxlength="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Event ID*</td>
<td><input type="text" onblur="validateEventId()" name="EventId" id="EventId" size="5" maxlength="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Date (YYYY-MM-DD)*</td>
<td><input type="text" onblur="validateDate()" name="Date" id="When" size="10" maxlength="10"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Finish time (HH:MM:SS)*</td>
<td><input type="text" onblur="validateTime()" name="FinishTime" id="Time" size="8" maxlength="8"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Position*</td>
<td><input type="text" onblur="validatePosition()" name="Position" id="Position" size="5" maxlength="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Category ID*</td>
<td><input type="text" onblur="validateCategoryId()"name="CategoryId"  id="CategoryId" size="2" maxlength="3"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Age grade*</td>
<td><input type="text" onblur="validateAge()" name="AgeGrade"  id="Age" size="5" maxlength="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Personal best</td>
<td><input type="text" onblur="validatePB()" name="PB"  id="PB" size="1" maxlength="1"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submitrunnertime"  id="submitrunnertime" value="submit"/>
<hr/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JS

```
function validateForm() {
    return (validateRunnerId
        && validateEventId
        && validateDate
        && validateTime
        && validatePosition
        && validateCategoryId
        && validateAge
        && validatePB);
}


function validateRunnerId(ID) {
    var ID = document.getElementById('RunnerId').value;
    var legalEntry = /^\d{1,5}?$/;

    if (ID.length == 0) {
        RunnerId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The RunnerId can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(ID)) {
        RunnerId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The RunnerId must be a number from 1 to 99999";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        RunnerId.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validateEventId(ID) {
    var ID = document.getElementById('EventId').value;
    var legalEntry = /^\d{1,5}?$/;

    if (ID.length == 0) {
        EventId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The EventId can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(ID)) {
        EventId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The EventId must be a number from 1 to 99999";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        EventId.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validateDate(ymd) {
    var ymd = document.getElementById('When').value;
    var legalEntry = /^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/;

    if (ymd.length == 0) {
        When.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The date can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(ymd)) {
        When.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The date must be in format YYYY-MM-DD";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        When.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validateTime(tm) {
    var tm = document.getElementById('Time').value;
    var legalEntry = /^\d\d\:[0-5][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]$/

    if (tm.length == 0) {
        Time.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The finish time can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(tm)) {
        Time.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The finish time must be in format HH:MM:SS";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        Time.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validatePosition(pos) {
    var pos = document.getElementById('Position').value;
    var legalEntry = /^\d{1,5}?$/

    if (pos.length == 0) {
        Position.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The position can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(pos)) {
        Position.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The position must be a number from 1 to 99999";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        Position.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validateCategoryId(ID) {
    var ID = document.getElementById('CategoryId').value;
    var legalEntry = /^\d\d?[0]?$/;

    if (ID.length == 0) {
        CategoryId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The CategoryId can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(ID)) {
        CategoryId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The CategoryId must be a number from 1 to 100";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        CategoryId.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validateAge(agrade) {
    var agrade = document.getElementById('Age').value;
    var legalEntry = /^\d\d?\,?\d?\d?$/;

    if (agrade.length == 0) {
        Age.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The age grade can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(agrade)) {
        Age.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The age grade must be decimal number of maximum 2 integers and 2 decimals";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        Age.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validatePB(pbest) {
    var pbest = document.getElementById('PB').value;
    var legalEntry = /^(0|1)$/;

    if (pbest.length == 0) {
        pbest.value = "0";
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(pbest)) {
        PB.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The PB can only be 0 for false and 1 for true";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        PB.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for taking the time to help this rookie :)

Comment: Those functions look quite odd. For instance, `validateRunnerId` declares that it accepts an `ID` argument, but then in the very next line you declare an `ID` variable and set its value. So the `ID` argument, even if given when calling the function, would never be used.

Comment: would it be best to remove the ID argument on function validateRunnerId?

Comment: @ Joy: If you're not using the argument (and in that case, you're not), yes. Note that several of the others do something similar.

Comment: you are a star, much appreciated! this is my first js ever...

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
function validateForm() {
    return (validateRunnerId
        && validateEventId
        && validateDate
        && validateTime
        && validatePosition
        && validateCategoryId
        && validateAge
        && validatePB);
}
```

...you're not *calling* your functions, you're just referring to them. And since a function reference is truthy, that condition is always true and the form is always valid.

To *call* a function, you put `()` after it. Assuming your functions don't need arguments, that would just be:

```
function validateForm() {
    return (validateRunnerId()
        && validateEventId()
        && validateDate()
        && validateTime()
        && validatePosition()
        && validateCategoryId()
        && validateAge()
        && validatePB());
}
```

It's hard to tell, though, because a lot of your functions declare arguments but then also declare the same symbol as variables, which is odd to put it mildly.

Comment: @JoyAdamson: I don't understand your question. The functions seem to return false when they find a problem (just glancing at them), and because you've used `&&` in the above, the expression will be `false` if any of the functions returns false (and the subsequent functions will not be called, because the engine stops evaluating the expression as soon as it knows what the result will be).